# VSCode / OSX - Terminal fails with execvp(3) failed.: Permission denied

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

Any action that attempts to open a shell (Terminal > New, Run a script, etc.) fails. The following message flashes briefly:

- execvp(3) failed.: Permission denied

and then a persistent message appears:

- The terminal process “zsh ‘-l’” failed to launch (exit code: 1).

This occurs when VSCode is started from a Terminal window or from the program icon in Applications. It also occurs on both of my MacBooks (one Intel, one M1, both running Monterey).

Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be resolved in the January release:

- Version: 1.64.0 (Universal)
- Commit: 5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9

Terminal now starts uneventfully, even when the integrated shell is set to zsh.